# python use of variable from globals without defining it as global in thee local scope

Tags: python, scope

In the following script:

```
def update_dict(key):
   my_dict[key] = ...


mydict = dict()
k = ...
update_dict(k)
```

`my_dict` has not been declared in the class but it's been used in `update_dict`.
1- The interpreter allowed that to happen. Shouldn't python throw an error on that?
2- What problems could carry using a global variable without declaring it as global within the local scope where it's used? Does python uses a pointer to the global variable based on the variable name?

---

This snippet is a summary made by me and the full code follows this paragraph if you think (perhaps correctly?) that I did a mistake in my summary.  The equivalent to `mydict` here is `sites`.

```
import sys
import csv
import argparse
import gzip

class SiteStats:
    def __init__(self, g_size, g_seq):
        self.num_reads = 0
        self.called_sites = 0
        self.called_sites_methylated = 0
        self.group_size = g_size
        self.sequence = g_seq

def update_call_stats(key, num_called_cpg_sites, is_methylated, sequence):
    if key not in sites:
        sites[key] = SiteStats(num_called_cpg_sites, sequence)

    sites[key].num_reads += 1
    sites[key].called_sites += num_called_cpg_sites
    if is_methylated > 0:
        sites[key].called_sites_methylated += num_called_cpg_sites

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description='Calculate methylation frequency at genomic CpG sites')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--call-threshold', type=float, required=False, default=2.0)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--split-groups', action='store_true')
args, input_files = parser.parse_known_args()
assert(args.call_threshold is not None)

sites = dict()
# iterate over input files and collect per-site stats
for f in input_files:
    if f[-3:] == ".gz":
        in_fh = gzip.open(f, 'rt')
    else:
        in_fh = open(f)
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(in_fh, delimiter='\t')
    for record in csv_reader:

        num_sites = int(record['num_motifs'])
        llr = float(record['log_lik_ratio'])

        # Skip ambiguous call
        if abs(llr) < args.call_threshold * num_sites:
            continue
        sequence = record['sequence']

        is_methylated = llr > 0

        # if this is a multi-cpg group and split_groups is set, break up these sites
        if args.split_groups and num_sites > 1:
            c = str(record['chromosome'])
            s = int(record['start'])
            e = int(record['end'])

            # find the position of the first CG dinucleotide
            sequence = record['sequence']
            cg_pos = sequence.find("CG")
            first_cg_pos = cg_pos
            while cg_pos != -1:
                key = (c, s + cg_pos - first_cg_pos, s + cg_pos - first_cg_pos)
                update_call_stats(key, 1, is_methylated, "split-group")
                cg_pos = sequence.find("CG", cg_pos + 1)
        else:
            key = (str(record['chromosome']), int(record['start']), int(record['end']))
            update_call_stats(key, num_sites, is_methylated, sequence)

# header
print("\t".join(["chromosome", "start", "end", "num_motifs_in_group", "called_sites", "called_sites_methylated", "methylated_frequency", "group_sequence"])
)

sorted_keys = sorted(list(sites.keys()), key = lambda x: x)

for key in sorted_keys:
    if sites[key].called_sites > 0:
        (c, s, e) = key
        f = float(sites[key].called_sites_methylated) / sites[key].called_sites
        print("%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%.3f\t%s" % (c, s, e, sites[key].group_size, sites[key].called_sites, sites[key].called_sites_methylated, f, sites[k
ey].sequence))
```

Thank you!

Comment: "1- The interpreter allowed that to happen. Shouldn't python throw an error on that?" No, why would it? When would the error arise and why?

Comment: "2- What problems could carry using a global variable without declaring it as global within the local scope where it's used?" None at all. It is **never** necessary to use `global` when you merely want to *use* a global variable. Rather, it is only necessary when trying to assign to a global variable inside a function. Indeed, using `global` in `update_dict` would be *confusing* because people reading it would expect you to mutate that global variable (assign or re-assign to it)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 1- It's assigning a key to an object that has not been declared as dict. Where does the class knows that it should use a global variable?

Comment: **Your class never uses a global variable**. In any case, **you never need to declare a variables as global merely to use it**. Please read what I've written. Perhaps `some_dict[key] = value` is confusing you, it is not a simple assignment, e.g. `x = y`, rather, it is "item assignment", basically syntactic sugar for `some_dict.__setitem__(key, value)` You only ever need to use a `global some_var` statement when `some_var` is *assigned to* in some non-global scope

Comment: "It's assigning a key to an object that has not been declared as dict." That doesn't make any sense. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding, python doesn't *have* variable declarations, and variables *don't have types* in Python, it is a dynamically typed language. Whatever is happening in `update_dict` happens at runtime and it is resolved at runtime when you call the function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I start to see it... Where could I learn very fast the basics of how dynamically typed languages work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global varname` is only needed when you are assigning to the global variable, because otherwise it is assumed to be a new local that is created. For all other cases, Python already knows that its supposed to be the global being used and there is no ambiguity.

In your sample code, you are setting a key/value pair on a global dict, not assigning to a global variable:

```
def update_dict(key):
    my_dict[key] = ...
```

The following would be a case where you need `global` in order to modify the global b:

```
b = 0
def a():
    global b
    b = 2
print(b)
a()
print(b)
```

Output:

```
0
2
```

Comment: the class function IS assigning to a global variable. However, there is no `global varname`. Also, you CAN'T sassing a new key to a `new local object` that has not been declared as `dict`. I am surprised that the scripts works but I suspect that the results could be wrong.

Comment: @aerijman what? Nowhere do you assign to a global variable in methods of your class.

Comment: `mydict[key] = ...` is not an assignment to `mydict`. It's syntactic sugar for `mydict.__setitem__(key, ...)`, and there is no `NameError` as long as `mydict` is defined in a containing scope before `update_dict` is *called*. Specifically, `mydict` does not need to be defined at the time `update_dict` itself is defined.

Comment: @chepner 1- Thank you! I have a hard time understanding this. Is it a good practice to declare functions that will use variables to be declared in the future rather than passing them to the function as arguments?

Comment: Not really, no. Pass values as arguments when possible.